# Unit Testing BelongsToMany relations in Sequelize using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm building a simple blog style application for practice using Node and Sequelize (with the Yeoman angular-fullstack generator). I'm trying to write out some tests for my article model, but I'm unable to figure out the right way to structure my tests. The articles and users are connected by a two-way belongsToMany relationship.

I'm able to verify that the setter and getter methods exist for my objects, but am unable to verify that they work. The code I'm trying to get to work is the code commented out at the end of the file. I'd appreciate any help in getting that unit test to work correctly, thanks!

```js
'use strict';

/* globals describe, expect, it, beforeEach, afterEach */

var app = require('../..');
import request from 'supertest';
import {User, Article} from '../../sqldb';

var user = [];
var article = [];

var genArticles = function(i) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    article[i] = genArticle(i);
  }
  return article;
}

var genUsers = function(i) {
  for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    user[i] = genUser(i);
  }
  return user;
}

var genUser = function(i) {
  return User.build({
    provider: 'local',
    name: `Fake User ${i}`,
    email: `test${i}@example.com`,
    password: 'password'
  });
};

var genArticle = function(i) {
  return Article.build({
    title: `Fake Article ${i}`,
    body: `test${i}`
  });
};

describe("Article-User relations", function() {
  before(function() {
    return User.sync().then(function() {
      return User.destroy({ where: {} }).then(function() {
        return Article.sync().then(function() {
          return Article.destroy({ where: {} }).then(function() {
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    genArticles();
    genUsers();
    done();
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    return User.sync().then(function() {
      return User.destroy({ where: {} }).then(function() {
        return Article.sync().then(function() {
          return Article.destroy({ where: {} }).then(function() {
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });

  it('should begin with no data', function() {
    expect(User.findAll()).to
      .eventually.have.length(0);
    return expect(Article.findAll()).to
      .eventually.have.length(0);
  });


  describe("Check methods exist and", function(done) {
    before(function(done) {
      article.forEach((a) =>  {a.save()});
      user.forEach((a) =>  {a.save()});
      done();
    });
    it("should have setter methods", function() {
      expect(typeof article[0].setUsers).to.equal("function");
      expect(typeof user[0].setArticles).to.equal("function");
    });
    it("should have getter methods", function() {
      expect(typeof article[0].getUsers).to.equal("function");
      expect(typeof user[0].getArticles).to.equal("function");
    });

    /* THIS IS THE TEST THAT ISN'T WORKING */

    /*
    it("setter and getter methods for article objects should work", function() {
      return article[0].setUsers(user).then(() => {
        return article[0].hasUsers(user).then( result => { 
          expect(result).should.eventually.equal.true;
        })
      }).catch( e => { console.log(e) });
      //expect(typeof user[0].setArticles).to.equal("function");
    });
    */

  });
});
```